# Reusing component to avoid circular dependency in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, circular-dependency, circular-reference, angular-module

I have a component module **'A'** with a button which opens component in module **'B'** (imported as a dependency into module **'A'**).

Now component module **'B'** uses component inside **'A'**, this is done to avoid code duplication, with an obvious code error with circular dependency between two modules with the below error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access **'B'** before initialization.

How do I overcome this issue. Please suggest.

Here is an example of the scenario I am trying to use:

**Update:** [StackBlitz link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-circular-dependent-modules)

**Module A** imports **Module B** imports **Module C** which imports **Module A**

Comment: you could try to use `forwardRef(() => ...)` to solve this problem

Comment: uploaded a stackblitz example, for your reference.

Comment: ah, I see. that architecture is not supposed to work. you should restructure how your application is built

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do it:

**1. Shared module**
You can have a shared `module` which is imported in both `Modules` ( A & B ) and use the services to share data.

**2. NGRX Store**.
You can subscribe to the `store` from the components and share data. Any component from any module that can access the `store` and `dispatch` an `action` receives data.

Comment: uploaded a stackblitz example, for your reference.